# Microsoft Cognitive Services JavaScript Request 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, azure-cognitive-services

Hy, when I try to access the Microsoft Cognitive Services API via JavaScript from my server/local machine I get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myUrl.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

This is my request code:

```
function requestAPI(){
var params = {
        // Request parameters
        "visualFeatures": "Categories"
};

$.ajax({
        url: "http://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{myKey}");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: "{'url':'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
```

}

In my .htaccess I already added:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

When I test the request with hurl.it it works. Just from my server it doesn't.

Comment: And with `Header set` for all of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting CORS headers for your server which means someone can make cross-domain request to your server.

Microsoft Cognitive Services have to add these headers on their server so that you can make cross-domain request to them or you have to use [JSONP](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: "or you have to use JSONP" — which Microsoft would also have to implement.